# Dynamic Tool Tip directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have got a requirement to work on a tool tip directive. I have searched on many sites, but couldn't find the exact answer.
My requirement: when the mouse hovers over a button, I should display a field `data` which should come from a field in restcall data.

What i have tried is:

I have used this directive:

```
.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $(element)
                .attr('title',scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip))
                .tooltip({placement: "right"});

        }
    }
})
```

Restcall data:

```
[
 {

        "informationName": "adf",
        "informationDescription": "desc"

    },
    {

        "informationName": "adsf",
        "informationDescription": "adsf"

    },
    {

        "informationName": "info001",
        "informationDescription": "info desc."

    }
]
```

HTML file:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="false">
    <tr ng-repeat="information in $data">

    <td>
    <button class="btn"  tooltip="information.informationName">Button
    </button>
    </td>
```

The problem:
I am sorry, I couldn't post the image because of some post error here..

In my output I am getting both `{{information.informationName}}` and `adf` on mouse hover but I should get only `adf`.

Comment: [UI Bootstrap - tooltip](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip)

Comment: this link doesn`t help me...what i actually need is a directive for generating dynamic text when mouse hover over a button...

Comment: My problem is solved....thnq...